# ip forwarding between two LANs

Tags: networking, router, ip-forward

I have 1 server which has 3 NIcs:

1. Connected to the Internet
2. Connected to LAN1 (10.0.0.0/24)
3. Connected to LAN2 (192.168.0.0/28)

   LAN2 has a server that works on a port, say 4444.
   How can I forward traffic from a specific port between the LANs? I want that only LAN1 is able to access the Internet and LAN2 isn't. All the machines are Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is do enable IP forwarding. This is done either by using

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Then, we will add a rule telling to forward the traffic

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i LAN1 -o LAN0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i LAN0 -o LAN1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o LAN0 -j MASQUERADE
```

On this way `LAN1` can go to internet through `LAN0`.

Edit 1

Try this

Example to route traffic for port 4444 and you can implement for port you need for

Let’s start from the iptable. Here we shall take `4444` as the service for routing. Use `mangle` table of iptable for modifying the `4444` packets.

```
  sudo iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp –dport 4444 -j MARK –set-mark 0×1
```

We are marking all packets with destination port `4444` as ’0×1′ .

To delete this entry from `iptables` we can use `-D` instead of `-A`.

Next, create a new IP route table in `/etc/iproute2/rt_table` by just giving an entry

```
100 4444table
```

Write rule for `4444` packets.

```
ip rule add fwmark 0×1 lookup 4444table
```

Add route at new table `4444table`. Here we shall use ’192.168.1.1′ as the gateway for `4444`. Address ’192.168.1.1′

We copy all entries except default gateway entry from main table.

```
 sudo ip route show table main | grep -Ev ^default | while read ROUTE ; do ip route add table 4444table $ROUTE; done
```

Add default gateway entry for `4444` packets to table `4444table`

```
  sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 table 4444table
```

Use `ip route show table 4444table` to show all routes at `4444table`.

Comment: so `LAN1` and `LAN0` in these commands are the NIC names? Do you know the commands for traffic forwarding between the  two LANs?

Comment: Yes. Your are right. Change with real interface names.

Comment: I add one command more in `iptables`

Comment: add command for traffic redirection? can you share the command?